# Select matching elements, but not children of those matching elements, without knowing the matching elements' nested positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Please suggest a better title to make this question easier to find for other users.**

I'm attempting to select a child of a parent element, but the child may be a child of a child, with no limit on how many nested children. I want to select that child, but if there is a child of that child within many nested children, I don't want that child to be selected. For example:

```
<div class="section">
<div>  <!--First nested child (Take this and repeat as many times as you want within the parent 'section' class, structure of nested children changing each time.)-->
    <div>  <!--Second nested child (Can have potentially infinite sub-nests like first, second, etc.)-->
        <div class="block">  <!--Select this -->
        Select
            <div>
                <div class="block">  <!--DONT select this -->
                Don't select
                    <div class="section">
                        <div>  <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                            <div class="block">  <!--Select this-->
                            Select
                                <div>
                                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>  <!--DONT select this -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="block">  <!--Select this -->
        Select
            <div>
                <div class="block">  <!--DONT select this -->
                Don't select
                    <div class="section">
                        <div>  <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                            <div class="block">  <!--Select this-->
                            Select
                                <div>
                                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>  <!--DONT select this -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

That looks awfully terrible, but the idea is that we only want to select the first occurrence in any children, and then no more after that.

I would obviously prefer CSS to do this selection, however we can utilize a jQuery selector if necessary. I'm not sure if it's possible in CSS.

A fiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/1/

> There are three solutions to this question. I've selected the pure CSS one from Arman P. as the answer because that was what the question asked for in preference and it is the fastest and simplest of the solutions.
>
> The second best is from Susanne Peng due to simplicity and minimal use of jQuery. Not sure about efficiencies, but it works.
>
> The third is ibrahim mahrir who was the first to solve, and utilizes a custom javascript function with dependency on jQuery.
>
> Recommend using the CSS solution if possible in this situation. Working fiddle with solution is in the comments on that answer.

Comment: Try to be more clear what you want with better example. I couldn't get what you want exactly.

Comment: I've answered your question. But then I came back to read the comments of the HTML code you provided and I'm begining to suspect It's not the right answer. So you want only the first `.block` element of the `.section` subtree. Right?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That is correct. See the fiddle I commented on your answer.

Comment: @ArmanP. I've updated the answer with more elements and a fiddle if you'd like to mess with that. Does that help, or do you need more clarification?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Actually, I want the all `.block`s of every `.section` without selecting children `.block`s of each selected `.block`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I want to style only the first level `.block` elements within the `.section` element. There may or may not be a `.block` element within the `.section .block` element.

Comment: @forrestmid Try this css `div:not(.block) > div:not(.block) > .block { color:blue; }`

Comment: @ArmanP. Almost, but no. If there is a `.block` that is not nested in a `div` and is an immediate child or a second level child of `.section` it doesn't work.

Comment: @forrestmid For the second level child it must work, to encounter for first-level child I have posted my answer with updated fiddle with both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with just CSS.

A solution using jQuery:

```
$('.section').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.block').first().css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/2/

If there could be multiple child `.block`s found under one `.section` you can take an approach like this:

```
$('.block').each(function() {
    var $closest = $(this).parent().closest('.section, .block');
    if ($closest.hasClass('section')) $(this).css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/5/

Comment: Not quite. Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/4/ It looks like it's not selecting multiple `.block`s within each `.section`

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
$(function(){
    // get the depth
    var count = $(".section").length;
    // array of matched elements
    var elements = [];

    // generate a selector for the '.section' that has a depth of 'depth'
    function getSelector(depth){
        var selector = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
            selector += ".section ";
        return selector;
    }

    // for each depth select only the first '.block' level of that depth
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        // selector for the '.section' on this depth
        var selector = getSelector(i + 1);
        // select the '.block' of this depth that aren't children of other '.block' of this depth too.
        $(selector + ".block").not(selector + ".block .block").each(function(){
            // push all the matched element into the array
            elements.push(this);
        });
    }

    console.log(elements);
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**

your CSS is wrong see this example it works:

```js
$(function() {
  // get the depth
  var count = $(".section").length;
  // array of matched elements
  var elements = [];

  // generate a selector for the '.section' that has a depth of 'depth'
  function getSelector(depth) {
    var selector = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
      selector += ".section ";
    return selector;
  }

  // for each depth select only the first '.block' level of that depth
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // selector for the '.section' on this depth
    var selector = getSelector(i + 1);
    // select the '.block' of this depth that aren't children of other '.block' of this depth too.
    $(selector + ".block").not(selector + ".block .block").each(function() {
      // push all the matched element into the array
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  color: red;
}
.block.selected {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div>
    <!--First nested child (Take this and repeat as many times as you want within the parent 'section' class, structure of nested children changing each time.)-->
    <div>
      <!--Second nested child (Can have potentially infinite sub-nests like first, second, etc.)-->
      <div class="block">
        <!--Select this -->
        Select
        <div>
          <div class="block">
            <!--DONT select this -->
            Don't select
            <div class="section">
              <div>
                <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                <div class="block">
                  <!--Select this-->
                  Select
                  <div>
                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>
                    <!--DONT select this -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="block">
        <!--Select this -->
        Select
        <div>
          <div class="block">
            <!--DONT select this -->
            Don't select
            <div class="section">
              <div>
                <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                <div class="block">
                  <!--Select this-->
                  Select
                  <div>
                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>
                    <!--DONT select this -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                <div class="block">
                  <!--Select this-->
                  Select
                  <div>
                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>
                    <!--DONT select this -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also rejected the title suggestion because I don't think it accurately represents the issue.

Comment: @forrestmid check the new answer it give exactly the result you want.

Comment: It isn't working for me. Is the implementation incorrect in this fiddle? It looks like it matches yours quite closely. https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/3/

Comment: you didn't include the jQuery here.

Comment: On that one I did. Look at external resources. On the original no, but on the one I commented just a few seconds ago yes.

Comment: @forrestmid Your CSS is wrong (two classes are always stronger than just one class, see CSS specifity). see example above.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't realize I was messing up that CSS. You're a wizard! What a non-trivial problem to solve. Any recommendation for the title for this now that you understand it more thoroughly? If someone else has this issue I doubt they'll find this with the current title.

Comment: @forrestmid Check please my only css solution.

Comment: Actually, ibrahim, there is another case in which it doesn't work. We're talking infinite here. :) https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/7/

Comment: @forrestmid Have you seen my updated answer? I believe it handles the complicated case you just made http://stackoverflow.com/a/41905039/2566368 :)

Comment: Actually, ignore that for one second. I might have messed up the tree ibrahim.

Comment: Mine work for as much deep as it can gets. Plus it not dependent of how many levels of `div`s are in the same `.setion` (between a `.block` and another `.block`) as the CSS answer abobe.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, why wouldn't **[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** work? It searches for the first element that matches your selector query. **This is really just a matter of knowing how to write proper [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).**

Also note that when you have a node reference, you will always have the descendant nodes accessible through that reference as well. That's the nature of of the DOM.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var selector = document.getElementById("query").value;
  var node = document.querySelector(selector);
  var childNodes = node.querySelector("*");
  console.log("Found node: " + node);
  console.log("Node contents: " + node.innerHTML);

  node.setAttribute("class", "special");
  childNodes.setAttribute("class", "normal");

});
```

```css
code.q { font-weight:bold; color:#f00; }

.special { color:#0f0; }
.normal  { color:#000; }
```

```html
<div class="section">
<div>  <!--First nested child (Take this and repeat as many times as you want within the parent 'section' class, structure of nested children changing each time.)-->
    <div>  <!--Second nested child (Can have potentially infinite sub-nests like first, second, etc.)-->
        <div class="block">  Select this
            <div>
                <div class="block">  DONT select this
                    <div class="section">
                        <div>  <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                            <div class="block">  Select this
                                <div>
                                    <div class="block"></div>  DONT select this
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<p>You can get whatever node you want, regardless of the DOM structure, you just have to know how to write your CSS selectors properly.</p>
<ul>
  <li>To get the first <code class="q">.block</code>, the selector would be: <code class="q">.block</code></li>
  <li>To get the third nested <code class="q">.block</code>, the selector would be: <code class="q">.block .block .block</code></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="query" value=".block">
<button>Search!</button>
```

Comment: It is possible this works, but I have only the .section and .block selectors, period. I don't know how many nested children there are of the block. Additionally, if `querySelector` only selects the first iteration, it won't work. I need it to select all iterations which are the first found child, regardless of nesting, of .block from .section. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, that search function returns the first `.section .block` that occurs, but not the `.section .block .block .section .block`, nor the second `.section .block` that I added in my edit.

Comment: It looks like that is only selecting the first visible "Select this" and not the second one, that is nested within the second section. It needs to search every section, and find all of the first blocks in each section, but not activate children of those blocks with the class `.block`.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS selection works as per the HTML currently provided but not sure if it may fail in other scenarios, it kinda depends on how the nesting may look like.

```
.section .block{
  color: red;
}

.section > * > .block, .section > * > * > .block{
  color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3owtetfb/1/

It could also be "reversely selected" which I believe will work more accurately if the nesting is irregular, see:
https://jsfiddle.net/xqf0u40r/

Comment: Like I had said, nesting is completely unknown. This will only work when nesting is known, but nesting can change when multiple `.section`s are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need this css selectors as far as I understand:
See working example below

```css
.section .block {
  color: red;
}

*:not(.block) > *:not(.block) > .block,
.section > .block {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<div>  <!--First nested child (Take this and repeat as many times as you want within the parent 'section' class, structure of nested children changing each time.)-->
    <div>  <!--Second nested child (Can have potentially infinite sub-nests like first, second, etc.)-->
        <div class="block">  <!--Select this -->
        Select
            <div>
                <div class="block">  <!--DONT select this -->
                Don't select
                    <div class="section">
                      <div class="block">  <!--Select this-->
                        Select
                        <div>
                          <div class="block">Don't select</div>  <!--DONT select this -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="block">  <!--Select this -->
        Select
            <div>
                <div class="block">  <!--DONT select this -->
                Don't select
                    <div class="section">
                        <div>  <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                          <div>
                            <div class="block">  <!--Select this-->
                            Select
                                <div>
                                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>  <!--DONT select this -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>  <!--More unknown nestings to an assumed infinite degree-->
                          <div>
                            <div class="block">  <!--Select this-->
                            Select
                                <div>
                                    <div class="block">Don't select</div>  <!--DONT select this -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `divs` don't matter, I've updated my answer to ignore the tag. But I see in your fiddle that you want to select childs of `.block`, are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, you got it. Working fiddle with CSS https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/10/ Sorry bout that!

Comment: If you've got a recommendation for title please make it. This is going to be really hard for other users to find with such a monster title.

Comment: @forrestmid This solution is actually incorrect as it still depends on a finite and known number of `div`s separating the `.section` and `.block`: https://jsfiddle.net/78b3c6xh/11/